# Can there be a feed (web or RSS) that ignores minor - or all - edits?

Tags: feature-request, sorting, feed, active

On medium sized sites, keeping track with the full site activity is nearly impossible:

- If you read only question posting order; you miss any new (and frequently good) answers to old questions
- If you try to read in "active" order (or the site RSS feed which follows that order), 90% if not more of posts that appear there are listed because of some truly insignificant edit (1 new tag, <10 characters edit) and/or Community user bumping the post.

  This means that on sites of a certain size (such as SciFi.SE) reading the active updates/RSS feed is basically not feasible.

Can there please be a third option added for sorting the questions (don't care if it's web or RSS); that shows the questions in active update order - the same as today's RSS - BUT ignored the "trivial" activity (small edits, tag-only edits, community user bumps).

The lack of this functionality **poses downside to both the site in general since less community moderation happens on new content for older questions** - as well as to individual users who are missing out on reading potentially great content posted on old questions.

As a easier to implement alternative, a more restricted version of it would be showing only "new post" activity (e.g. questions that have new answers only; ignore ALL edits/bumps).

Comment: This would be nice. "New questions and new answers only, no edits"

Comment: For people visiting the site daily (or more frequently), a sort mechanism that ignores edits (or at least trivial edits) would work. As an RSS user, I need something that prevents my inbox from being slammed with any sort of edits.

Answer (score 4):

Given that a lot of these "please add another feed..." feature requests aren't addressed quickly, you can use the Stack Exchange API to get the same information, though it will take some effort on your part if you really need a feed:

The following API function doesn't require authentication, but you are rate limited if you don't get an API key.  It returns all posts (questions and answers) and you can sort it by creation date, so it only returns the newest items, ignoring modification date (edits):

http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts#order=desc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=scifi&run=true

You'll want to fiddle with the exact query, setting a date range, or a number of items returned, and since it's JSON you'll need to write a script to convert it to your preferred feed format, but if you can't wait then this will provide the information you need.

Here's an example query for the SciFi site:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts?order=desc&sort=creation&site=scifi